# Force both HTTPS and HTTP with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several domains under the same server, but my https certificated only works for one of them.

1. I need to force https for: `mydomain1.com`
2. All other domains (`mydomain2.com`, `mydomain3.com` ...) must use
   http.

I know it must be a simple rule, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your [hosts](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) file

Comment: I don't have access to it. It's a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

if port is not SSL and domain is mydomain1.com, force redirect to https://

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain1.com$  
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```